# grid-auto-columns doesn't make auto columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to let `div`s be inline, but `grid-auto-columns` does not make auto columns.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 12vh;
  grid-template-rows: 12vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#container div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue Regular";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I used `grid-template-rows` and `grid-auto-columns`, and I expected the each `div` to follow right behind the previous one as square. However, they were compressed for some reason. 
I could make it with `grid-template-columns: 12vh 12vh 12vh 12vh;`, but I want to do it with `grid-auto-columns` because the number of boxes can be changed as the number of contents changes. 
How can I do this and why does this happen? 
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for `grid-auto-flow: columns` then you can specify `grid-template-columns` with a `minmax` repeat where your min is an auto-fill and your max is a given unit measurement. try: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(12vh, 1fr));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 12vh;
  grid-template-rows: 12vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#container div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue Regular";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help.